# How to put random number in int array C

Tags: c

I would like to pass a random number i generate to an int array. I get something but its not right.

Thanks in advance,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
   int i, n;
   time_t t;

   n = 5;

   int haystack [n];



   /* Intializes random number generator */
   srand((unsigned) time(&t));

   /* Print 5 random numbers from 0 to 50 */
   for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) 
   {
      printf("%d\n", rand() % 50);
      haystack[i] = rand();
      printf("%d\n", haystack[i]);

   }

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: What is _not right_?

Comment: int haystackp[] prints numbers but not the ones i generated with srand time and rand until number 50. It generates his own, with its own seed.

Comment: You are calling rand() twice, you will get two different random numbers. If you would like to reuse the random number, store it in a variable and reuse it in your print and assignment statement.

Answer (score 3):

this prints random numbers < 50:    `printf("%d\n", rand() % 50);`

this generate new random numbers with no such limitation: `haystack[i] = rand();`

there is no reason for them to be equal.

I guess you want something like:

```
haystack[i] = rand() % 50;
printf("%d", haystack[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that each call to `rand` give you back a new/"different" value.

Assign the number to the array first, then print it

```
   /* Print 5 random numbers from 0 to 50 */
   for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) 
   {
      haystack[i] = rand() % 50;
      printf("%d\n", haystack[i]);

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the issue with the unitialised variable t, you're using a different random value in your `printf` then you store in your `haystack`.

```
   /* Print 5 random numbers from 0 to 50 */
   int rand = 0;
   for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) 
   {
      rand = rand() % 50;
      printf("%d\n", rand);
      haystack[i] = rand;
      printf("%d\n", haystack[i]);

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look ok to me, but did you mean to print a different `rand()` to the one you're storing in `haystack`?

You can address this by collapsing the `for` loop body to the single statement

`printf("%d\n", haystack[i] = rand() % 50);`

Answer (score 0):

```
  printf("%d\n", rand() % 50);
  haystack[i] = rand();
```

1. You are using rand() two times, first in printf and next in assignment.

   So every time rand() will generate different values so that will not equal to the previous value.
2. In printf() rand()%50 will give the value less that 50, but in assignment operation it may exceed 50 so take care of it. But still prefer to use rand() once only in one assignment.

Hope this will help